# how to validate the post action method in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

im using javascript function for simple client side validation

```
 `function IsCodeEmpty() {
            if (document.getElementById('InputCode').value == "") {
                return 'Patient Code should not be empty';
            }
            else { return ""; }
        }

function IsVisitNoInValid() {
    if (document.getElementById('VisitNo').value== "") {
        return 'Visit No should not be empty';
    }

    else { return ""; }
}

function IsValid() {

    var CodeValidationMessage = IsCodeEmpty();
    var IsVisitNoInValidMessage = IsVisitNoInValid();
    var FinalErrorMessage = "Errors:";
    if (PatientCodeValidationMessage != "")
        FinalErrorMessage += "\n" + CodeValidationMessage;
    if (IsVisitNoInValidMessage != ""
        FinalErrorMessage += "\n" + IsVisitNoInValidMessage;

    if (FinalErrorMessage != "Errors:") {
        alert(FinalErrorMessage);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}`
```

and my view is `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddPatient</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/add.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/Validation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="~/Main/Screen" method="post">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">TEST ORDER FOR PATIENT</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <h3><label class="control-label"> CODE<span class="inp">*</span></label></h3><input type="text" id="InputCode" name="InputCode" value="" style="height:30px;" /><br />

                    <h3><label class="control-label">VISIT NO<span class="inp">*</span></label></h3><input type="text" id="visitno" name="VisitNo" value="" style="height:30px;" /><br />

                    <br />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add" type="submit" onclick="return IsValid()";>ADD</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>`
```

and why i cant get my validation message. it doesnt show any validation message.
i added scripts link on my head section in view. then why iam not getting run javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The right bracket of the 4-th `if` condition statement is missed.
2. The  `visitno` is not equals to `VisitNo`. You need to replace `visitno` identificator with `VisitNo` in your HTML or replace `VisitNo` with `visitno` in javascript .

See working code below.

```js
function IsCodeEmpty() {
  if (document.getElementById('InputCode').value == "") {
    return 'Patient Code should not be empty';
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

function IsVisitNoInValid() {
  if (document.getElementById('VisitNo').value == "") {
    return 'Visit No should not be empty';
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

function IsValid() {
  var CodeValidationMessage = IsCodeEmpty();
  var IsVisitNoInValidMessage = IsVisitNoInValid();
  var FinalErrorMessage = "Errors:";
  if (CodeValidationMessage != "") FinalErrorMessage += "\n" + CodeValidationMessage;
  if (IsVisitNoInValidMessage != "") FinalErrorMessage += "\n" + IsVisitNoInValidMessage;
  if (FinalErrorMessage != "Errors:") {
    alert(FinalErrorMessage);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">TEST ORDER FOR PATIENT</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <h3><label class="control-label"> CODE<span class="inp">*</span></label></h3><input type="text" id="InputCode" name="InputCode" value="" style="height:30px;" /><br />

      <h3><label class="control-label">VISIT NO<span class="inp">*</span></label></h3><input type="text" id="VisitNo" name="VisitNo" value="" style="height:30px;" /><br />

      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add" type="submit" onclick="return IsValid()" ;>ADD</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanku its working. i just dont know  that id and must be the same  as in co ntrol m